# How to host the backend of react native application to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have built a simple application, with backend and frontend separated.
I don't know how to deploy the backend to Heroku.

Comment: What are you trying to deploy ? In the title you're asking how to host a react application, so your frontend, but in your post you say that you don't know how to deploy the backend, this is not really clear.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy the backend

Comment: You can follow this tutorial then, it will help you https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-node-applications-on-heroku-a89ed51e0a34